# Print all shipments which are delivered within 7 days of courier Start date

Tags: python, dictionary

```
a= {101: {'Sender': 'Phillip', 'Receiver': 'Ramya', 'Start date': '14-03-2020', 'Delivery date': '25-03-2020', 'Sender location': 'Area 1', 'Receiver location': 'Area 6', 'Delivery status': 'Delivered', 'Shipping cost': 198}, 102: {'Sender': 'Romesh', 'Receiver': 'Phillip', 'Start date': '18-06-2020', 'Delivery date': '09-07-2020', 'Sender location': 'Area 2', 'Receiver location': 'Area 4', 'Delivery status': 'Delivered', 'Shipping cost': 275}, 103: {'Sender': 'Omega lll', 'Receiver': 'Ramya', 'Start date': '01-12-2020', 'Delivery date': 'Null', 'Sender location': 'Area 5', 'Receiver location': 'Area 1', 'Delivery status': 'In-Transit', 'Shipping cost': 200}, 104: {'Sender': 'Phillip', 'Receiver': 'John', 'Start date': '23-06-2020', 'Delivery date': '25-06-2020', 'Sender location': 'Area 1', 'Receiver location': 'Area 4', 'Delivery status': 'Delivered', 'Shipping cost': 314}, 105: {'Sender': 'Ramya', 'Receiver': 'Romesh', 'Start date': '29-08-2020', 'Delivery date': '10-09-2020', 'Sender location': 'Area 5', 'Receiver location': 'Area 3', 'Delivery status': 'Delivered', 'Shipping cost': 275}, 106: {'Sender': 'John', 'Receiver': 'Omega lll', 'Start date': '28-06-2020', 'Delivery date': 'Null', 'Sender location': 'Area 3', 'Receiver location': 'Area 1', 'Delivery status': 'In-Transit', 'Shipping cost': 270}}
```

** I tried this using filter function but stuck how to compare the dates **

```
Start_date= list(filter(lambda value: value['Start date' in 'Delivery Date'] ,a.values()))
print(Start_date)
```

Can someone help me please

Comment: Convert the times to `datetime.datetime` objects using `datetime.datetime.strptime(time_string, format)` where `time_string` is element from your dictionary (such as `'23-06-2020'`) and `format` is `'%d-%m-%Y'`. If you difference two of these objects you will get a `datetime.timedelta` object which you can then compare with `datetime.timedelta(days=7)`. This should be enough to get you started.

Comment: A cool alternative is also `dateutil.parser.parse`. You can pass the time string directly to it without having to worry about format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to convert string to `datetime` object:

```py
from datetime import datetime

for v in a.values():
    if v["Delivery date"] == "Null":
        continue

    start = datetime.strptime(v["Start date"], "%d-%m-%Y")
    delivery = datetime.strptime(v["Delivery date"], "%d-%m-%Y")

    if (delivery - start).days <= 7:
        print(v)
```

Prints:

```py
{'Sender': 'Phillip', 'Receiver': 'John', 'Start date': '23-06-2020', 'Delivery date': '25-06-2020', 'Sender location': 'Area 1', 'Receiver location': 'Area 4', 'Delivery status': 'Delivered', 'Shipping cost': 314}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use lambda filter?